# How to use $templateCache for partials that are used in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-templatecache

.state ('pages', {
      url: '/pages',
      templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
    })

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="common.html">
```

how to use this using Ui-router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be helpful to you

```
var myApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

myApp.run(['$templateCache',function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('common.html', ' <p>how to use this using Ui-router?</p>');
   $templateCache.put('views/common.html', ' <p>how to use this using Ui-router?</p>');
}]);

myApp.config(['$stateProvide','$templateCache',function($stateProvider,$templateCache){
$stateProvider.state ('pages',
     { url: '/pages',
       template: $templateCache.get('common.html')   
     })
.state ('pages', 
     { url: '/pages', 
       templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
     })
}]);

myApp.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
})

    <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but here if i follow the way you have implemented, i need to write inline html like $templateCache.put('common.html', ' <p>how to use this using Ui-router?</p>'); is there any way if we an use external html.

Comment: you can use the script template 
 and for further reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: ya i followed the same way but

Comment: yes i am unable to use templateCahe inside app.config as i am using ui-router i am importing the partials in templateurl in formszWebApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
    $stateProvider
    .state ('common', {
      url: '/common',
      templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
    })});

Comment: did you added `ng-route` or `ui.router`

Comment: i am using ui-router,and have child states so i want to templatecache all the html files as i can get rid of those html files when i check them in dev tools. a 200 service requeest will be saved

Comment: `.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider","$templateCatch",function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$templateCatch) { }])`